# Do I need to know about Dart before starting Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a JavaScript developer I want to learn Flutter, and my question is before starting Flutter, Do I need to know about Dart lang, Do I need to watch any Dart course.

Comment: Yes, because dart has different structure than javascript. You need to know oop in dart

Comment: If you know another langage, no. It's designed to be familiar to the mainstream languages

Comment: dart is similar to other languages but you can find some helpful features that will make your flutter development better and more productive if you know about them. short answer is no. long answer is yes, in order to gain more insight and know more about the cool features of the language. check this article to understand me better:                                  https://renato.athaydes.com/posts/interesting-dart-features.html#callable-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart is very similar to Javascript.

Here are a few differences to know coming from Javascript:

- Dart is a statically typed language (does type checks at compile time like Typescript, even though you can disable those with the `dynamic` variable type) with strong type inference (will try its best to guess the type without you declaring it)
- Dart is object-oriented and uses classes more heavily than Javascript (where object `{}` is commonly used as a multiple purpose data structure)
- Dart has some syntax features that JS doesn't, like:

  - Safe-navigation operator: `var name = address?.street?.name;`
  - Collection-if: `print([1, for(int i in [1, 2, 3]) i + 1, 5]);  //= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
  - Very powerful [constructors](https://flutterigniter.com/deconstructing-dart-constructors/) and streams library
- JS has some other that Dart doesn't

  - Destructuring assignment
  - Variable number of arguments (but you can use named arguments in Dart)

**I think you should just get started with Flutter and you will learn Dart as you go.**

If you are interested in learning most syntactic differences between Javascript and Dart, I wrote a full comparison here: https://flutterigniter.com/ultimate-javascript-dart-syntax-guide/

Another great way to learn is using [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev) as a code playground (see the Samples dropdown).

Answer (score 0):

If you are accustomed to ReactJS/React Native then transitioning to Flutter will be a smooth experience.

Dart is very similar to JS and C so you need to be an expert in Dart to jump into Flutter.